# Check whether value in list of tuples

Tags: python, jinja2

I am writing macro for Jinja which displays devices. And I have list of devices like:

```
[('ios', 'something'),
 ('android', 'something'),
 ('windows', 'something'),
 ('blackberry', 'something')]
```

I need to display it in specific order which not guaranteed by server logic. Unfortunately some of devices my be not presented. Also second parameter of each tuple is unpredictable, so I cannot use `in` check. I cannot change it on server (have not rights).

Comment: With custom template tags, it's really easy. Have you got permissions to create or modify these?

Comment: @Danstahr I have access only to the `templates` directory, so I thing I haven't.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you actually have coming from the server? Is it actually a list of tuples as shown that you wish to order somehow?

Comment: It is list of tuples where first item is platform name and second item is not used by my logic and my be absolutely random. Some tuples may be missing (for example entry with `android` and `blackbery`). No sorting method is known. I need `ios` always first, then android, then windows and blackberry last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do things in Jinja, you can get the first element of each tuple in a list of tuples with

```
devices|map(attribute=0)
```

where `devices = [('device1', 'string'), ('device2', 'string')]` is your list of tuples.

Comment: Have you checked it inside Jinja template? It is not working because Jinja does not provides list comprehension as it described in documentation.

Comment: Are you getting the list outside the Jinja template? Because then you could filter out the first element before passing it to Jinja.

Comment: Inside Jinja, you can filter the first element out of each tuple using a `map` filter: `devices|map(attribute=0)`.

Comment: Yep, with your last comment your solution is working. Could you please update answer so other people may use it?